# Cannot change active text color on TabLayout

Tags: android

I am trying to style tabs in an android.support.design.widget.TabLayout  I can not get the selected tab color to change, it is always set to the textColorPrimary in my app theme, but I need them to be different colors.

I have tried setting values in styles.xml that applies to TabLayout, but I read you can not change active tab text color this way, though I can change unselected tab text colors.  I have also tried:

```
tabLayout.setTabTextColors(getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.selector));
```

and

```
tabLayout.setTabTextColors(R.color.Green, R.color.Blue);
```

Is it possible to override the selected tab text color?

Comment: This answer is what you are looking for
https://stackoverflow.com/a/31471430/2163045

Answer (score 14):

Edit: got it working,

```
tabLayout.setTabTextColors(getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.selector));
```

needed called before it was attached to the view pager

Comment: Is this working for you in v23.0.1 of the support design lib?

Comment: I was trying to use android:textColor="@color/tab_text_color_selector" in the TabLayout xml, but had to use your way with design v23.1.1.  Not sure why this is so! :-/  I'll keep looking at my code, but this does the trick.  FWIW: getResources(...) is not deprecated.

Answer (score 14):

Actually you CAN customize active tab text color via defining custom `TabLayout` style. Look at `tabSelectedTextColor` parameter. Here is example of customizing `tabSelectedTextColor`, `tabIndicatorColor`, `tabTextAppearance` (text size/color etc):

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@style/CustomTabLayoutStyle"/>
```

Styles:

```
<style name="CustomTabLayoutStyle" parent="Base.Widget.Design.TabLayout">
    <item name="tabSelectedTextColor">@color/tab_text_selected</item>
    <item name="tabIndicatorColor">@color/tab_indicator</item>
    <item name="tabTextAppearance">@style/CustomTabTexStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomTabTexStyle" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Tab">
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/tab_text</item>
    <item name="textAllCaps">false</item>
    ...
</style>
```

Comment: note.. must be `style`, won't work with `android:theme`

Answer (score 9):

Add below code to your xml:

```
app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/app_color"
```