# Text size of android design TabLayout tabs

Tags: android, text-size, android-tablayout

I have difficulties changing the text size of the tabs of design library tablayout (android.support.design.widget.TabLayout).

I managed to change it by assigning tabTextAppearance in TabLayout

```
app:tabTextAppearance="@style/MyTabLayoutTextAppearance"
```

the following style

```
<style name="MyTabLayoutTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title.Inverse">
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
</style>
```

but I have 2 side effects :

1) I lost the accent color of the selected tab

2) The tab text is not capitalized any more.

Answer (score 238):

```
<style name="MineCustomTabText" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Tab">
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
</style>
```

Use is in `TabLayout` like this

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            app:tabTextAppearance="@style/MineCustomTabText"
            ...
            />
```

Comment: Working fine. I'm using support lib 25.1.0.

Comment: Works on support library 25.3.1

Comment: superb thax bro you save my time  ,,,   its working on lib 25.1.0

Comment: @Sufian, it not working for me and I am using the same support version as you (25.1.0). Any idea why?

Comment: @Sam try doing a clean build. If it doesn't work then post your code here.

Comment: If your tab text is multiline. Then the tabLayout it using a different field to set the texts size. Please checkout my answer here for solution : https://stackoverflow.com/a/48797329/700693

Answer (score 60):

Go on using tabTextAppearance as you did but

1) to fix the capital letter side effect add textAllCap in your style :

```
<style name="MyTabLayoutTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title.Inverse">
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
</style>
```

2) to fix the selected tab color side effect add in TabLayout xml the following library attributes :

```
app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/color1"
app:tabTextColor="@color/color2"
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @u2gilles i have used custom layout in tabs that is linearlayout with 2 textviews but i want to change only one textview color on tab selection  ?

Comment: If you want to set <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item> then t here should be  one more string in addition to twos : 
      <item name="textAllCaps">false</item>

Answer (score 35):

Work on api 22 & 23
Make this style :

```
<style name="TabLayoutStyle" parent="Base.Widget.Design.TabLayout">
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
</style>
```

And apply it to your tablayout :

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/contentTabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/list_gray_border"
    app:tabTextAppearance="@style/TabLayoutStyle"
    app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    app:tabTextColor="@color/colorGrey"
    app:tabMode="fixed"
    app:tabGravity="fill"/>
```

Answer (score 24):

Do as following.

**1. Add the Style to the XML**

```
    <style name="MyTabLayoutTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Tab">
        <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
    </style>
```

**2. Apply Style**

Find the Layout containing the TabLayout and add the style. The added line is bold.

```
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        app:tabTextAppearance="@style/MyTabLayoutTextAppearance" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Answer (score 21):

Try the snipped which is mentioned below, it works for me also.

In my layout `xml` where I have my `TabLayout`, have added style to the `TabLayout` like below :

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
    style="@style/MyCustomTabLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    app:tabMode="fixed" />
```

and in my `style.xml` I have defined the style that is used in my layout xml, check code for styles added below :

```
<style name="MyCustomTabLayout" parent="Widget.Design.TabLayout">
    <item name="android:background">YOUR BACKGROUND COLOR</item>
    <item name="tabTextAppearance">@style/MyCustomTabText</item>
    <item name="tabSelectedTextColor">SELECTED TAB TEXT COLOR</item>
    <item name="tabIndicatorColor">SELECTED TAB INDICATOR COLOR</item>
</style>

<style name="MyCustomTabText" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Button">
    <item name="android:textSize">YOUR TEXT SIZE</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

I hope it will work for you.....

Answer (score 17):

I have similar problem and similar resolution:

1) Size

in the xml you have TabLayout,

```
        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            ...
            app:tabTextAppearance="@style/CustomTextStyle"
            ...
        />
```

then in style,

```
        <style name="CustomTextStyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.TabWidget">
           <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
           <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
        </style>
```

If you do not want the characters in uppercase put false in "android:textAllCaps"

2) Text color of selected or unselected Tabs,

```
TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        tabLayout.setTabTextColors(getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.tab_selector,null));
    } else {
        tabLayout.setTabTextColors(getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.tab_selector));
    }
```

then in res/color/tab_selector.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:color="@color/white" android:state_selected="true" />
<item android:color="@color/white" />
```

Answer (score 10):

```
TabLayout  tab_layout = (TabLayout)findViewById(R.id.tab_Layout_);

private void changeTabsFont() {
    Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "fonts/"+ Constants.FontStyle);
    ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) tab_layout.getChildAt(0);
    int tabsCount = vg.getChildCount();
    for (int j = 0; j < tabsCount; j++) {
        ViewGroup vgTab = (ViewGroup) vg.getChildAt(j);
        int tabChildsCount = vgTab.getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < tabChildsCount; i++) {
            View tabViewChild = vgTab.getChildAt(i);
            if (tabViewChild instanceof TextView) {
                ((TextView) tabViewChild).setTypeface(font);
                ((TextView) tabViewChild).setTextSize(15);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code is works for me using tablayout.
It will change size of fonts and also change font style.

This will also help you guys please check this link

https://stackoverflow.com/a/43156384/5973946

This code works for Tablayout change text color,type face (font style) and also text size.

Answer (score 1):

I was using Android Pie and nothing seemed to worked so I played around with app:tabTextAppearance attribute. I know its not the perfect answer but might help someone.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption" />
```

Answer (score 0):

XML FILE IN VALUES

```
<style name="tab">
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/_10ssp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
</style>
```

TAB LAYOUT

```
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/_27sdp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_10sdp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:tabTextAppearance="@style/tab"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
   >

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TAB 1"
        android:scrollbarSize="@dimen/_4sdp"
        />

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbarSize="@dimen/_6sdp"
        android:text="TAB 2" />

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbarSize="@dimen/_4sdp"
        android:text="TAB 3" />
</com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>   **create custom style in styles.xml**  <style name="customStylename"
> parent="Theme.AppCompat">
>         <item name="android:textSize">22sp</item>  <item name="android:color">colors/primarydark</item>
>     </style>
> 
>   **link to your material same name **  
> <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout  
> android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
>         android:id="@+id/tabs"
>         app:tabTextAppearance="@style/customStylename" 
>       />
```

> this is my solution

Answer (score 0):

```
fun TabLayout.customizeTabSizeAndFont() {
    val tabFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.assets, "font.ttf")
    val tabTextSize = 21f
    val viewGroup = this.getChildAt(0) as ViewGroup
    for (tabVGPos in 0..viewGroup.childCount) {
        val tabViewGroup = viewGroup.getChildAt(tabVGPos) as ViewGroup?
        tabViewGroup?.let {
            for (tabPos in 0..tabViewGroup.childCount) {
                val tab = tabViewGroup.getChildAt(tabPos)
                if (tab is TextView) {
                    tab.typeface = tabFont
                    tab.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, tabTextSize)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```